# How to successfuly connect the IR Gateway to Redshift and pull the data?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Can anyone tell me how can we successfully connect the IR Gateway to Redshift and pull the data into Azure, currently I am not able to connect to redshift, I have white listed the Integration Runtime IP in the AWS Security rolls, is there any way by which we can find out what is the IP of the IR?

Answer (score 0):

did you use Self-hosted Integration Runtime? If yes, the IP address of the IR should be IP address of the machine it's installed on. Follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-authorize-cluster-access.html) to see how to grant access for IR to Amazon Redshift.